# How can I get a sublist with wraparound in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy, slice, numpy-slicing

## Simple 1D case

I would like to get a substring with wraparound.

```
str = "=Hello community of Python="
#      ^^^^^               ^^^^^^^  I want this wrapped substring

str[-7]
> 'P'

str[5]
> 'o'

str[-7:5]
> ''
```

Why does this slice of a sequence starting at a negative index and ending in a positive one result in an empty string?

How would I get it to output "Python==Hell"?

---

## Higher dimensional cases

In this simple case I could do some cutting and pasting, but in my actual application I want to get every sub-grid of size 2x2 of a bigger grid - with wraparound.

```
m = np.mat('''1 2 3; 
              4 5 6; 
              7 8 9''')
```

And I want to get all submatrices centered at some location `(x, y)`, including `'9 7; 3 1'`. Indexing with `m[x-1:y+1]` doesn't work for `(x,y)=(0,0)`, nor does `(x,y)=(1,0)` give `7 8; 1 2`

#### 3D example

```
m3d = np.array(list(range(27))).reshape((3,3,3))
>
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])

m3d[-1:1,-1:1,-1:1]
# doesn't give [[[26, 24], [20, 18]], [8, 6], [2, 0]]]
```

If need be I could write some code which gets the various sub-matrices and glues them back together, but this approach might get quite cumbersome when I have to apply the same method to 3d arrays.

I was hoping there would be an easy solution. Maybe numpy can help out here?

Comment: *Why does this slice of a sequence starting at a negative index and ending in a positive one result in an empty string?* It's not about positive/negative, it is that your lower end of the range (-7 == 7) is bigger than your upper end (5).

Comment: Could you provide some more examples of the higher dimensional case? Like 2d and 3d. What exactly is the input and what is the expected output?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco updated description

Comment: Do you actually need negative indexes, or would larger-than-size indexes also suffice? Like trying to get all substrings with `for i in range(len(s)): print(s[i:i+3])`.

Comment: @KellyBundy yeah, but that gives a similar problem. `"test"[2:5]` gives `'st'` instead of `'stte'`

Comment: That's why "trying". It was just to illustrate what I meant with the different indexes.

Comment: Python indexing (with slice notation) does  not do wrap around - whether its lists, strings or numpy.  You have to select the two parts and join them.  In numpy you can concatenate (advanced) indexing arrays first.

Comment: @hpaulj *"You have to select the two parts and join them"* - I'd say my first answer disproves that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) (see the section starting with *"From a 4x3 array the corner elements should be selected using advanced indexing"*):

```
import numpy as np

m = np.mat('''1 2 3; 
              4 5 6; 
              7 8 9''')

print(m[np.ix_(range(-1, 1), range(-1, 1))])
print(m[np.ix_(range(-2, 2), range(-2, 2))])
print(m[np.arange(-2, 2)[:, np.newaxis], range(-2, 2)])
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3X2XmFuQXlSjkleYWVCokFivkFXBx5SrYAmm93MQSDXV1dUMFIwVjawUuBRRgomCqYIYhaq5goWAJ1KPJxVVQlJlXopEbDTQosyJeoygxLz1VQ9dQR8FQU0cBmacZq4lDsZGOghFCMZiHpjgRWS7aSgfk7LzU8sSKzOJYVI2xmhAfQz0OCwAA)):

```
[[9 7]
 [3 1]]
[[5 6 4 5]
 [8 9 7 8]
 [2 3 1 2]
 [5 6 4 5]]
[[5 6 4 5]
 [8 9 7 8]
 [2 3 1 2]
 [5 6 4 5]]
```

### Going through all sub-matrices

Since you want to go through all sub-matrices, we can beforehand  separately prepare the row ranges and the column ranges, and then use pairs of them to quickly index:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.mat('''1 2 3; 
              4 5 6; 
              7 8 9''')

m, n = A.shape

rowranges = [
    (np.arange(i, i+2) % m)[:, np.newaxis]
    for i in range(m)
]
colranges = [
    np.arange(j, j+2) % n
    for j in range(n)
]

for rowrange in rowranges:
    for colrange in colranges:
        print(A[rowrange, colrange])
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZBNTsMwEIXFdk7xNiixMJUofyWIRY6BoiwslLaO8NhyXJWehU03cChOg5NgV4A3lt7M997MvH-6Q9haPh4_dmF9ufo6e9bGWR_AO-MOUAPYEdV4iv_CqFAWRXGFJa4fQfj1bnCLu3_qPVZ4iIwgMhIcferFsFWuI_J27xVvuiGKzYSVMUNNWqkl9MVS4BxGNJUc07nbqzc9tFPr2npoaMbcbgS19GJf_xie_HqJfvbjzPcnnkeeRjFNNdXShFVmUsZYznlVXtp5zaGsm0TK3NSK-cI_h04H_wY)):

```
[[1 2]
 [4 5]]
[[2 3]
 [5 6]]
[[3 1]
 [6 4]]
[[4 5]
 [7 8]]
[[5 6]
 [8 9]]
[[6 4]
 [9 7]]
[[7 8]
 [1 2]]
[[8 9]
 [2 3]]
[[9 7]
 [3 1]]
```

### 3D case

```
m3d = np.array(list(range(27))).reshape((3,3,3))
m3d[np.ix_(range(-1,1), range(-1,1), range(-1,1))]
```

Output:

```
array([[[26, 24],
        [20, 18]],

       [[ 8,  6],
        [ 2,  0]]])
```

Comment: There's a lot of information on that page that doesn't directly help me solve the problem. You might want to add the specific other answer you had in mind to your solution.

Nevertheless: this works! Thank you.

Comment: @TimKuipers Added now. I like the `ix_` way better, as it's simpler. But the other way could be faster in your real program, since you could prepare the different row ranges and the different column ranges, and then pair them up and use `m[rowrange, colrange]`.

Comment: @TimKuipers Added that as section "Going through all sub-matrices" now.

Comment: Which other? The one where you duplicate the whole array? Sounds like that one should be slower.

Comment: @TimKuipers You mean my other *answer*? No, I meant the other way in *this* answer. The one with `np.newaxis`.  Although... Now that I'm thinking about it ... My other answer actually could be faster (at least if you duplicate only as far as needed). I think that's still slicing and creates views, while the advanced indexing in *this* answer *copies* the data. Then again, when you actually *use* the sub-matrices, I guess views are accessed more slowly. So... I don't know. You'd have to test the different solutions with your real use case :-)

Answer (score 0):

Simply combine the two halfs yourself:

```
>>> str[-7:]+str[:5]
'Python==Hell'
```

Comment: How would that work for higher dimensional cases, e.g. in 3D arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You could repeat your data enough so that you don't need wraparound.

Substrings of length 3:

```
s = 'Python'
r = 3

s2 = s + s[:r-1]
for i in range(len(s)):
    print(s2[i:i+r])
```

Output:

```
Pyt
yth
tho
hon
onP
nPy
```

Sub-matrices of size 2×2:

```
import numpy as np

m = np.mat('''1 2 3; 
              4 5 6; 
              7 8 9''')
r = 2

m2 = np.tile(m, (2, 2))
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        print(m2[i:i+r, j:j+r])
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZA7DsIwEERFuy0XmM62SJBw-AZxB3pEkSKAo9ixbKfgLDQ0cChOgwlBSLDNakea0du53O05nBpzvd7acEiXj8HQYwO27VRGLh4ZkZdxe4zgd7lLJ3s6NA4KysAV5ljyujTcC5ET4linTOBe7lSuRm4viJS2jQswrbZnFB7GEumYaOxYF4EzxiaQyNbo_N-ZYob5n7rAEqvoER2djFHynRVUXXKdgMsEUohfyKzne8nVv_xF1z16giqvXh-8u-kr-lT1BA)):

```
[[1 2]
 [4 5]]
[[2 3]
 [5 6]]
[[3 1]
 [6 4]]
[[4 5]
 [7 8]]
[[5 6]
 [8 9]]
[[6 4]
 [9 7]]
[[7 8]
 [1 2]]
[[8 9]
 [2 3]]
[[9 7]
 [3 1]]
```

For larger more-dimensional arrays, the simple `np.tile` adds mmore than necessary. You really just need to increase the size by `+ r-1` in each dimension, not by `* 2`. Like I did with the string. Not sure how to do that well with arrays. Plus I think you can also make your negative indexes work, so we just need someone to come along and do that.